# How can I selectively choose the sum of values to be bigger than 3 in this MapReduce problem?

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I'm getting data from .edges files (Facebook social nodes). Each line in those files represents an edge in the graph. For example,

123       95

means there is an edge from node 123 to node 95.  For each node X, I am interested in the number of incoming edges from even numbered nodes. But I am only interested in nodes X that have at least 3 incoming edges from even numbered nodes.

My issue is the fact I have tried different for loops and am struggling in deriving sum(valuelist) values in my results where the sum(valuelist) is only greater than or equal to 3.

```py
from mrjob.job import MRJob


class WordCount(MRJob):
   def mapper(self, key, line):
      def even_number(key):
         if float(key) %2 == 0:
            return True
         else:
            return False
      split_word = line.split()
      if even_number(split_word[0]):
         yield(split_word[1], 1)

   def reducer(self, key, valuelist):
      yield key, sum(valuelist)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   WordCount.run()
```

If the input is:

```
22  7
32  7
33  7
34  7
7   6
2   6
8   6
```

then the output would be

```
7       3
```

because node 7 has 3 incoming edges from even numbered nodes. Node 6 has only 2 such incoming edges and since 2 < 3, it does not make it into the output. In the output files, the key should be the node number and the value should be the number of incoming edges it has from even numbered nodes.

This is the output I'm getting now in my results.

```
"979"   4
"98"    21
"980"   53
"981"   24
"982"   36
"983"   29
"984"   21
"985"   4
"986"   4
"987"   2
"988"   16
"989"   14
"99"    3
"990"   22
"991"   7
"992"   13
"993"   65
"994"   10
"995"   27
"996"   0
"997"   43
"998"   4
"999"   35
```

Notice some of the 2nd column -> sum(valuelist) -> is lesser than 3.. this is not what I want as the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter out the results in the reducer

```
def reducer(self, key, valuelist):
    count = sum(valuelist)
    if count >= 3:
        yield key, count
```